# clojure.java.jdbc lazy query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I have a query that is basically a `select *`. In development this table is only 30000 rows, but in production it will much bigger. So I want to consume this query lazily. Why is the query below not lazy?
I am using Postgres 9.5.4.1.

```
(do
  (def pg-uri {:connection-uri "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/..."})
  (def row (atom 0))
  (take 10 (clojure.java.jdbc/query 
          pg-uri
          ["select * from mytable"]
          {:fetch-size 10
           :auto-commit false
           :row-fn (fn [r] (swap! row inc))}))
  @row) ;;=> 300000
```

Comment: Maybe this older S.O. question and answers would be relevant, not sure:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728538/clojure-java-jdbc-query-large-resultset-lazily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clojure.java.jdbc` supports lazy processing of large result sets natively these days (the other answers here predate that native support). See the community documentation about it here:

http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql#processing-a-result-set-lazily

In particular, see the **Additional Options?** section for database-specific tweaks you might need. You can specify `:auto-commit? false` on any function that would open a new connection, and you can specify `:fetch-size` and the various cursor controls on any query-related function. See this StackOverflow question & answer for details of what PostgreSQL might need:

[Java JDBC ignores setFetchSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468036/java-jdbc-ignores-setfetchsize)

Currently, you'll have to dig in the `clojure.java.jdbc` source [or the `prepare-statement` reference documentation](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/prepare-statement) for more of those options. I'm continuing to work on the community documentation to surface all of that information.

Answer (score 9):

First, see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/query.html#query-with-cursor.

Solved it like this.

```
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx connection]
  (jdbc/query tx
    [(jdbc/prepare-statement (:connection tx)
                              "select * from mytable"
                              {:fetch-size 10})]
     {:result-set-fn (fn [result-set] ...)}))
```

where `:result-set-fn` is a function that consumes the lazy result set.

`with-db-transaction` takes care of `autoCommit` set to `false`.
`:fetch-size` is not passed from `query` so you have to make a `prepare-statement` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the transaction and prepared-statement stuff above.  It is the use of `:result-set-fn` that causes the lazy-sequence to be consumed.  You may have meant to use `:row-fn` instead.

For full details [please see The Clojure Cookbook.](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc)  A print version is also available, which I recommend.

> The jdbc/query function has several optional keyword parameters that
>   control how it constructs the returned result set. The :result-set-fn
>   parameter specifies a function that is applied to the entire result
>   set (a lazy sequence) before it is returned. The default argument is
>   the doall function:

```
(defn hi-lo [rs] [(first rs) (last rs)])

;; Find the highest- and lowest-cost fruits
(jdbc/query db-spec
            ["select * from fruit order by cost desc"]
            :result-set-fn hi-lo)
;; -> [{:grade nil, :unit nil, :cost 77, :appearance nil, :name "Kumquat"}
;;     {:grade 1.4, :unit nil, :cost 10, :appearance "rotten", :name "Tomato"}]
```

> The :row-fn parameter specifies a function that is applied to each
>   result row as the result is constructed. The default argument is the
>   identity function:

```
(defn add-tax [row] (assoc row :tax (* 0.08 (row :cost))))

(jdbc/query db-spec
             ["select name,cost from fruit where cost = 12"]
             :row-fn add-tax)
;; -> ({:tax 0.96, :cost 12, :name "Plum"} {:tax 0.96, :cost 12, :name "Fig"})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work with Postgres. See the link in my answer. You need to set autoCommit to false and the fetchSize in order to make fetching with a cursor work or else the whole result set will still be in memory. Verify by turning on Postgres logs:

LOG:  execute fetch from S_1/C_2: select * from ...

The word 'fetch' here is what you should see with using a cursor.
Another check you can do is 'select all' on a big table and record the time vs. a limited query. You'll see that the limited query is much faster, but with fetching it doesn't matter.

Comment: You'll see that the limited query is much faster, but with using a cursor it doesn't matter => that is, if you only realize for example the first element.

Comment: So perhaps is it only lazy on the Clojure side, not on the JDBC/Postgres side then... I haven't experimented that far.  You may wish to send this question to the clojure Google Group, as the maintainer of clojure.java.jdbc is frequently there.

Comment: Exactly. I already found the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39775018/6264) . There's an open issue for `:fetch-size` not being passed down to prepare-statement in clojure.java.jdbc.

Comment: I've added an answer here that talks about setting `:auto-commit?` and `:fetch-size` and the new (0.7.0+) `reducible-query` function as the best way to deal with this, with links to the recently updated community documentation about `clojure.java.jdbc`.